# Abort instead of segfault with clear memory violation

Tags: c, memory-management

I came upon this weird behaviour when dealing with C strings. This is an exercise from the K&R book where I was supposed to write a function that appends one string onto the end of another string. This obviously requires the destination string to have enough memory allocated so that the source string fits. Here is the code:

```
 /* strcat: Copies contents of source at the end of dest */
 char *strcat(char *dest, const char* source) {
  char *d = dest;
  // Move to the end of dest
  while (*dest != '\0') {
    dest++;
  } // *dest is now '\0'

  while (*source != '\0') {
    *dest++ = *source++;
  }
  *dest = '\0';
  return d;
}
```

During testing I wrote the following, expecting a segfault to happen while the program is running:

```
int main() {
  char s1[] = "hello";
  char s2[] = "eheheheheheh"; 
  printf("%s\n", strcat(s1, s2));
}
```

As far as I understand s1 gets an array of 6 `chars` allocated and s2 an array of 13 `chars`. I thought that when `strcat` tries to write to s1 at indexes higher than 6 the program would segfault. Instead everything works fine, but the program doesn't exit cleanly, instead it does:

```
helloeheheheheheh
zsh: abort      ./a.out
```

and exits with code 134, which I think just means abort.

Why am I not getting a segfault (or overwriting s2 if the strings are allocated on the stack)? Where are these strings in memory (the stack, or the heap)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I thought that when strcat tries to write to `s1` at indexes higher than `6` the program would segfault.

Writing outside the bounds of memory you have allocated on the stack is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Invoking this undefined behaviour usually (but not always) results in a segfault. **However, you can't be *sure* that a segfault will happen.**

The wikipedia link explains it quite nicely:

> When an instance of undefined behavior occurs, so far as the language specification is concerned anything could happen, maybe nothing at all.

So, in this case, you could get a segfault, the program could abort, or sometimes it could just run fine. Or, anything. There is no way of guaranteeing the result.

> Where are these strings in memory (the stack, or the heap)?

Since you've declared them as `char []` inside `main()`, they are arrays that have [automatic storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Storage_duration_specifiers), which for practical purposes means they're on the stack.

Comment: +1 for stating 'undefined behaviour' — that's the crucial element.  When you trample outside the bounds of an array, anything can happen, and it is a legitimate response to the undefined behaviour.

Comment: Hmm, far more concise than me... And a +1 for the link to automatic storage. I wasn't sure that it was on the stack but I suspected. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 1:**

I'm going to try and explain how you might go about discovering the answer for yourself. I'm not sure what actually happens as this is not defined behavior (as others have stated), but you can do some simple debugging to figure out what your compiler is actually doing.

**Original Answer**

My guess would be that they are both on the stack. You can check this by modifying your code with:

```
int main() {
  char c1 = 'X';
  char s1[] = "hello";
  char s2[] = "eheheheheheh"; 
  char c2 = '3';

  printf("%s\n", strcat(s1, s2));
}
```

`c1` and `c2` are going to be on the stack. Knowing that you can check if `s1` and `s2` are as well.

If the address of `c1` is less than `s1` and the address of `s1` is less than `c2` then it is on the stack. Otherwise it is probably in your `.bss` section (which would be the smart thing to do but would break recursion).

The reason I'm banking on the strings being on the stack is that if you are modifying them in the function, and that function calls itself, then the second call would not have its own copy of the strings and hence would not be valid... However, the compiler still knows that this function isn't recursive and can put the strings in the `.bss` so I could be wrong.

Assuming my guess that it is on the stack is right, in your code

```
int main() {
  char s1[] = "hello";
  char s2[] = "eheheheheheh"; 
  printf("%s\n", strcat(s1, s2));
}
```

`"hello"` (with the null terminator) is pushed onto the stack, followed by `"eheheheheheh"` (with the null terminator).

They are both located one after the other (thanks to plain luck of the order in which you wrote them) forming a single memory block that you can write to (but shouldn't!)... That's why there is no seg fault, you can see this by breaking before `printf` and looking at the addresses.

`s2 == (uintptr_t)s1 + (strlen(s1) + 1)` should be true if I'm right.

Modifying your code with

```
int main() {
  char s1[] = "hello";
  char c = '3';
  char s2[] = "eheheheheheh"; 
  printf("%s\n", strcat(s1, s2));
}
```

Should see `c` overwritten if I'm right...

However, if I'm wrong and it is in the `.bss` section then they could still be adjacent and you would be overwriting them without a seg fault.

**If you really want to know, disassemble it:**

Unfortunately I only know how to do it on Linux. Try using the `nm <binary> > <text file>.txt` command or `objdump -t <your_binary> > <text file>.sym` command to dump all the **symbols** from your program. The commands should also give you the **section** in which each symbol resides.

Search the file for the `s1` and `s2` symbols, if you don't find them it should mean that they are on the stack but we will check that in the next step.

Use the `objdump -S your_binary > text_file.S` command (make sure you built your binary with debug symbols) and then open the `.S` file in a text editor.

Again search for the `s1` and `s2` symbols, (hopefully there aren't any others, I suspect not but I'm not sure).

If you find their definitions followed by a `push` or `sub %esp` command, then they are on the stack. If you're unsure about what their definitions mean, post it back here and let us have a look.

Comment: This is **probably** what's happening. But, it's not guaranteed. The standard doesn't say where in the stack the arrays are to be stored.

Comment: True, the **probably** is a big guess. I didn't actually run the code... I will when I get time since it is interesting.

Comment: Where behaviour that isn't specified by the standard (such as actual memory location of variables) is concerned, running the code is only going to get you a misleading answer, dependent on code/compiler version/architecture. I would say it's better to learn to write portable code, by understanding what the standard does and does not specify.

Comment: Correct, however debugging undefined behavior out of curiosity is not forbidden. I only tried to give him the capability to do so. I will clarify this in my answer.

Comment: Also, I think that it is a good exercise to learn how to manipulate your compiler into giving you the information you want. If you only learn about the standard and not about what your compiler does leaves you unable to beat it into submission when it misbehaves. If you know your compiler and perhaps a few others then you have greater appreciation for the standard.

Comment: @nonsensical Thanks for the suggestions of how to check where the string actually are. I did it by putting chars in between declarations and printing out the addresses. It turns out they are all over the memory (even the chars I put in between) and hence there is no overwriting - I checked that one before. I guess the memory after `s1` is somehow accessible enough to the program to not cause a segfault when written to, but it still causes an abort in the end.

Comment: There is one part that I left out as too hard but you seem pretty savvy so I might as well tell you. I'll update my answer with it.

Comment: You can disassemble your code to look for where the compiler has put it. But it seems we found something close to what you are after and if you're happy so am I. Glad that you found it useful.

Comment: Yeah. I could disassemble it, but it's quite a lot of effort. I don't know why I haven't thought of adding those extra chars to find the location. Thanks for your help! I guess the conclusion is don't do it that way ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's no seg fault  or even an overwrite because it can use the memory of the second string and still function. Even give the correct answer. The abort is a sign that the program realized something was wrong.  Try reversing the order in which you declare the strings and try again.  It probably won't be as pleasant.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
  char s1[] = "hello";
  char s2[] = "eheheheheheh"; 
  printf("%s\n", strcat(s1, s2));
}
```

instead  use:

```
   int main() {
  char s1[20] = "hello";
  char s2[] = "eheheheheheh"; 
  printf("%s\n", strcat(s1, s2));
}
```

Comment: s1 is not pointing to read only memory. I think the compiler automatically copies it into an appropriate array. If you look at my output `s2` actually gets copied at the end of `s1`, something I believe should cause a segfault, instead at the end of the program I get an abort.

Comment: The syntax `char s1[]="hello";` is a shorthand for `char s1[6]={'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};`, so that's not read-only memory as it would be with `char *s1="hello";`.  Also, the point of the question is not "how to fix it", but "why doesn't it segfault".

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yeah I make a mistake... Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reason why your program didn't crash:

Your strings are declared as array (s1[] and s2[]). So they're on the stack. And just so happens that memory for s2[] is right after s1[]. So when strcat() is called, all it does is moving each character in s2[] one byte forward. Stack as stack is readable and writable. So there is no restriction what you'e doing.

But I believe the compiler is free to locate s1[] and s2[] where it see fits so this is just a happy accident.

Now to get your program to crash is relatively easy

1. Swap s1 and s2 in your call: instead of strcat(s1, s2), do strcat(s2, s1). This should cause stack smashing exception.
2. Change s1[] and s2[] to *s1 and *s2. This should cause segfault when you're writing to readonly segment.

Answer (score 0):

hmm.... the strings are in stack all right since heap is used only for dynamic allocation of memory and stuff..

segfault is for invalid memory access, but with this array you are just writing stuff which is going out of bound (outside the boundry) for the array , so while writing i dont think you will have a issue .... Since in C its actually left to the programer to ensure things are kept in bound for arrays.

Also while reading if you use pointers - I dont think there will be a issue either since you can just continue to read till where ever you want and using the sum of previous lengths. But if you use functions that are mentioned in string.h they relay on the presence of the null character "\0" to decide where to halt the operation -- hence i think your function worked !!

but the termination could also indicate that any other variable / something that might have been present next to the location of the strings might have got over written with char value .... accessing those might have caused the program to exit !!

hope this helps .... good question by the way !